# virtualhost without real domain name

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

I've this configuration for my virtual host and runs with real domains. For testing purpose I need create same virtual host with non real domain (i.e. domain10). Considerated that the browser check the name of domain of virtual host, I think using something like 127.0.0.1. But I've no idea to realize this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@domain10.org
ServerName domain10.org
ServerAlias domain10.org

DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
DocumentRoot /home/domain10.org/

<Directory /home/domain10.org/>
Options -Includes -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI +MultiViews
AllowOverride none
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/etc/hosts` file for this purpose.  There should already be a line in it beginning with `127.0.0.1`.  Just add `domain10.org` to the list of hosts that resolves to this address.

For example, if the existing line is:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
```

Just extend it to:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain domain10.org
```

Then (on this machine only) `domain10.org` will resolve to `127.0.0.1`.  If you are testing on the same machine, you can enter `http://domain10.org/` in your browser to reach your local web server.

---

If you need to reach this host over the Internet, then a different approach is needed.  Look for a line for the *external* IP address of the server in its `/etc/hosts` file and modify it similar to the above instructions.  If such a line does not exist, add one.

On the client machine, do the same (using `/etc/hosts` for a Linux box or `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` for a Windows box).  You should then be able to reach the server from the client using this name.

Comment: Thank you :-) this server is over the internet so I need access to this virtual host by internet. Is there a way? thanks again